# How to run code to toggle ShowCursor on Outlook from Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using code on Outlook to hide the mouse cursor on Outlook before opening the attached workbook:

```vb
Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "USER32" (ByVal fShow As Integer) As Integer            
Public Sub hide_Cursor()
    ShowCursor False
End Sub
```

After the attached file is opened, I need to do the opposite (show the mouse cursor on Outlook).
I did not find any events on Outlook to run code after an attachment file is opened.

So, I need the following code to run from the Excel workbook.
It has no effect. The mouse cursor is still hidden on Outlook.

```vb
Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "USER32" (ByVal fShow As Integer) As Integer 
Public Sub Show_Cursor()
    ShowCursor True
End Sub
```

Comment: While Wend is a deprecated structure in VBA.  It is better to use Do While,,,,Loop.

Comment: What is the end goal of hiding and display back the cursor?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev ,I need to learn the concept, as the mouse cursor is got hidden on outlook only and on the same time appearing on other applications.

Comment: That is because the `ShowCursor` Windows API function works per process. You must call it again from the same process to return the cursor back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ShowCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor) function applies only to the process from which it was called. So, to get back the cursor you need to call the method from the Outlook process, not Excel.